# Image to a graph problem

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to use MorphologicalGrpah to produce a graph, but I tried with a different graph. It does not print the exact graph. Is there a way to fix it? Is there a program where I can draw a graph by my hand and convert it to Wolfram Language?

[image]

Comment: I am commenting on the OP because this addresses comments made in the two current answers: perhaps you may consider the value that would come with learning how to produce these graphs using the Wolfram Language, rather than trying to use the methods you are currently attempting. This is, in its current state, a problem of image recognition. If you continue down this path, you may find value in training a neural network to produce your desired outcome. This too can be done with the Wolfram Language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are determined to work from the way the graph has been drawn, then you need to modify the input image to get it into a form `MorphologicalGraph` can work with. This is one way of doing it - the idea is to fill in the circles where the vertices are then use `Thinning`:

`img=`[image]

Then (the value of 'r' arrived at from experiment):

```
With[{r = 12}, TopHatTransform[img, DiskMatrix[r]]] // Binarize // Erosion[#, 2] &;
ComponentMeasurements[%, "Mask", And[#Count > 200, .9 < #Circularity < 1.1] &, "ComponentAssociation"]//Binarize;
infill = ImageAdd[Image /@ % // Values]
```

[image]

Now add this back to the negation of the original image to fill in the disks:

```
filled = ImageAdd[ColorNegate[img] // Binarize, Dilation[infill, 3]]
```

[image]

Then use `Thinning`:

```
thinned = Thinning[filled]
```

[image]

Finally, `MorphologicalGraph`:

```
MorphologicalGraph[thinned]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I want to follow this procedure to other graphs, I just need to fix the "r" value? Another way to say it, can I use this procedure for any graph I see in a textbook?

Comment: @MubarakAlsaeedi no, the procedure I've shown works for the form of input image you showed, it won't generalise to "any" graph in a textbook, there are no end of ways graphs can be drawn.

Answer (score 5):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Z5W.png"]
```

[image]

We can identify the circles representing vertices and remove them and fill the spaces of removed vertices to get an image to pass to `MorphologicalGraph`:

```
img2 = Colorize @ DeleteBorderComponents @ MorphologicalComponents @ Binarize @ img
```

[image]

```
img3 = DeleteSmallComponents[img2, 500]
```

[image]

```
img4 = Binarize @ RemoveBackground @ ColorNegate @ img3
```

[image]

```
img5 = ColorNegate @ MorphologicalTransform[img4, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity]
```

[image]

```
MorphologicalGraph[img5, VertexSize -> Small]
```

[image]

***Note:*** The *magic* number `500` in step 3 is obtained by *squinting* at the `"Area"`, `"Circularity"`  and `"Rectangularity"` numbers for the 13 components of `img2`:

```
ComponentMeasurements[img2, {"Area", "Circularity", "Rectangularity"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now can I use this procedure to any graph?

Answer (score 3):

As per the "Applications" section of the documentation, you can use `ColorNegate`:

[image]

As per your comment: if you want to get Daniel Huber's graph from your image, try
`MorphologicalGraph[ColorNegate@Binarize@Erosion[i, DiskMatrix[20]]]` where `i` is the image.

[image]

Comment: It's good, but that does not give me the desired graph. The original graph has 9 vertices, but the graph you obtained has 24 Vertex.

Comment: @MubarakAlsaeedi Why don't you draw your graph in such a way that it is compatible with `MorphologicalGraph`? Clearly, the purpose of `MorphologicalGraph` is not to recognize arbitrarily-styles hand-drawn graphs, but to extract a graph from a branching structure.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can do that, but I'm searching for a way to convert an image to a graph. I'm currently studying a textbook with lots of graphs, and I want to insert them in Mathematica so I can play with them by capturing the graph and insert it as an image and then convert them to a graph.

Answer (score 3):

The circles in your drawing are recognized as branch point. Therefore, do not draw circles.

Here is an example picture:

[image]

With this pictures stored in `im`:

```
im = ColorNegate[im]
MorphologicalGraph[im]
```

We get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. One last question, is there a way when I study graphs in mathematics textbooks, I can capture them then convert them in Mathematica without drowning them without circles?

Comment: I am using: https://duckcapture.de.softonic.com/

Comment: thank you, I’m using Mac to capture easily; what I’m searching for is software like Mathpix (a software convert equations to LaTeX), but I want a software convert image to graph.