# How to creat a high-quality graph image for MorphologicalGraph to convert to graphs (it can't detect some edges in mine)?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

I'm using MorphologicalGraph to convert images to graph. This is my source image:[image: This is my source image]

Following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/how-to-convert-an-image-to-a-graph-and-get-the-positions-of-the-edges) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241230/image-to-a-graph-problem), I tried

```
i = Thinning[Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfVsG.png"],
    3, Method -> "MedialAxis"];
g = MorphologicalGraph[i, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5], Thickness[.01]], 
   GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"];
Show[Dilation[i, 1], g]
```

Below is the output, some edges are not detected while some are detected wrongly[image: output].

Could anyone help me with this? Is this caused by the image quality?

Comment: Try converting the image to grayscale, then dilate, binarize and thin  i.e. ColorConvert[i,"Grayscale"]//Dilation[#,1]&//Thinning then try MorphologicalGraph. BTW you've got two graphs in the image - the outer box and the inner more connected object

Comment: For `MorphologicalGraph`, a "vertex" is a branching point. The "corner" in the lower left of the image is not a branching point, so it will not be a vertex in the result. This is not incorrect behaviour. If you want that point detected, as a first step you would need to come up with a clear definition of what you consider a vertex.

Comment: The other issue is that `MorphologicalGraph` does not support multi-edges at this point. This is an unfortunate limitation. I have requested this feature from Wolfram multiple times. They are more likely to add it if more people request it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.